# How to add any specific class for current page when hash is being used

Tags: jquery, html

I have three separate links for same page.

Based on current page URL considering HASH(#) also, I want to add class in LI and Anchor tag using jQuery code.

Used below code but not working.

```
<ul class="menu">
<li><a href="https://example.com/faq">faqs</a></li>
<li><a href="https://example.com/assistance#pay_navi_method">payment methods</a></li>
<li><a href="https://example.com/assistance#service_center">service centre</a></li>
<li><a href="https://example.com/assistance#cust_delight">hotline</a></li>
<li><a href="https://example.com/assistance">assistance</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Try 1:**

```
jQuery(window).on('hashchange', function() {
  var hash = window.location.hash;
  jQuery('a').closest('li').removeClass('called');
  jQuery('a[href="' + hash + '"]').closest('li').addClass('called');
});
```

**Try 2:**

```
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('ul.menu li a[href^="/' + location.pathname.split("/")[1] + '"]').addClass('called');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with out jQuery and just use a CSS selector like so:

```
a[href$="#cust_delight"] { color: red; }
```

Using the `a[href$=""]` selector you can match elements based on the end of the anchors `href` value.

In your examples you where using `^` which is begins with, and the other you missed it out - so the selectors wouldn't match

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
<div id="foo">
    <a href="#foo">Foo</a>
</div>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function()
    {
        $(window).on('hashchange', function()
        {
            var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
            $('a[href="#'+ hash +'"]').closest('div').css('background', 'red')
        });
    })
</script>
```

This is an example of the functionality - adjust to suit your code.

Essentially what happens is, on page load - your url most likely  **won't** contain a hash value (unless user is already on page.php#location).

Your first try was extremely close, I just think how you were getting the hash was your fault.

Answer (score 1):

You can add class with url as follows

```
// Fetch current URL
var current_location = window.location.href;

// iterate each <a> of li to add class 'active' to matched element.
$(".menu li").each(function() {
  if ($(this).children("a").attr("href") == current_location) {
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(this).children("a").addClass("active");
  }
})
```

Comment: little bit resource-heavy no?

Comment: No not that much, will imapct if we have to iterate many more. There could not be much <li>. As it is depend on current URL so I think we can consider it.